# Random forest in TensorFlow 1.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-forest

Wanting to try some experiments with random forest classification in TensorFlow, by far the highest ranked example code on Google is https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/random_forest.py but when I try to run it as-is, I get this error:

```
C:\tf>random_forest.py
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tf\random_forest.py", line 45, in <module>
    forest_graph = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs(hparams)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tensor_forest\python\tensor_forest.py", line 376, in __init__
    tree_variables_class=tree_variables_class)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tensor_forest\python\tensor_forest.py", line 350, in __init__
    self.variables.append(tree_variables_class(params, i, training))
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tensor_forest\python\tensor_forest.py", line 318, in __init__
    params, '', self.get_tree_name('stats', tree_num))
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tensor_forest\python\ops\stats_ops.py", line 102, in fertile_stats_variable
    container, shared_name=name, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tensor_forest\python\ops\gen_stats_ops.py", line 141, in fertile_stats_resource_handle_op
    shared_name=shared_name, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3273, in create_op
    compute_device=compute_device)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3313, in _create_op_helper
    set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2501, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    return _set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2474, in _set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2404, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 627, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    require_shape_fn)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 686, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'FertileStatsResourceHandleOp' in binary running on PC. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process.
```

Seems to be an entirely internal error message, and no mention of it in the github issues, which suggests maybe a compatibility problem or something. TensorFlow 1.6.0, Python 3.6.4, Windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16855

Comment: @dgumo ah! finally at the end of comments, it says the problem is it doesn't work on Windows. Thanks!